# Shell script to ban an IP

Tags: command-line, scripts, iptables, connection

Some of the IPs are opening thousands of connections of my server. I have a Ubuntu 14 server. I check total connections using following command:

> netstat -an | grep tcp | awk '{print $5}' | cut -f 1 -d : | sort |
>   uniq -c | sort -n

Then I use following iptables rule to block the culprit IP.

> iptables -I INPUT 1 -s x.x.x.x -j DROP

It works all fine and block the IP address. However, I cannot stay online 24/7 to monitor server. I was wondering if there is any Shell script I can use to do it automatically? For example, if an IP opens more than X number of connections at any time, it should be automatically get banned by above iptables rule.

Comment: Have you looked to see if [fail2ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban) meets your needs?

Comment: Excuse my limited knowledge. Isn't fail2ban for ssh authentication? I am not sure to use it on port 80. In addition, my server is a chat-server, so a user can try to connect/ping multiple times. In this case, fail2ban would create many false-positive alarms and ban legitimate traffic. Any thought?

Answer (score 10):

First of all, don't reinvent the wheel. That's precisely what `denyhosts` is for:

```
   DenyHosts  is a python program that automatically blocks ssh attacks by
   adding entries to /etc/hosts.deny.  DenyHosts will  also  inform  Linux
   administrators  about  offending  hosts,  attacked users and suspicious
   logins.
```

As far as I know, `denyhosts` is only for `ssh` connections but there's also 
`fail2ban` that deals with pretty much anything:

```
   Fail2Ban consists of a client, server and configuration files to  limit
   brute force authentication attempts.

   The  server  program  fail2ban-server is responsible for monitoring log
   files and issuing ban/unban commands.  It  gets  configured  through  a
   simple  protocol  by fail2ban-client, which can also read configuration
   files and issue corresponding configuration commands to the server.
```

Both are available in the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install denyhosts fail2ban
```

---

You could also script this, if you like. Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
netstat -an | 
    awk -vmax=100 '/tcp/{split($5,a,":"); if(a[1] > 0 && a[1]!="0.0.0.0"){c[a[1]]++}}
    END{for(ip in c){if(c[ip]>max){print ip}}}' |
        while read ip; do iptables -I INPUT 1 -s "$ip" -j DROP; done
```

The `awk` will extract the IPs and count them and only print those that appear more than `max` times (here, `-vmax=100`, change it accordingly). The IPs are then fed to a while loop that runs the relevant `iptables` rule.

To run this 24/7, I would make a cronjob that runs the command above every  minute or so. Add this line to `/etc/crontab`

```
* * * * * root /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks terdon for a precise answer. AFAIK, fail2ban is for ssh authentication. All the connections are being opened on port 80. I will explore if I can use fail2ban on port 80. For the custom script, how could I run it 24/7 in the background? screen command? Or install cron? BTW. I am using server as a chat-server so a person can ping many times (or open multiple connections) so I might go for the custom script that you provided.

Comment: @user3404047 you could run it as a cronjob, yes. See updated answer. However, `fail2ban` is not only for ssh. It also works fine for port 80. See, for example [here](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/fail2ban-port-80-to-protect-sites-from-dos-attacks/), [here](http://blogs.buanzo.com.ar/2009/01/fail2ban-rules-for-lighttpd-fastcgi-alerts.html) and [here](http://serverfault.com/q/1423).

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative option is to identify and deal with the problem IP addresses all within the iptables rule set, using the `recent` module. The challenge with this method is the default hitcount limit of 20, so one needs to either deviate from the defaults or create higher level carry counters to achieve a higher hitcount trigger point.

The below example is from my iptables rule set, and will ban an ip address for just over 1 day if it makes 80 new TCP connections on port 80 in less than 12 minutes. Once on the bad guy list, any attempt to connect will reset the 1 day counter to 0. This method could go to a maximum 400 hits before expansion to another carry would be required (and I have tested another carry chain). Note that the code as posted has the infrastructure to be used to only ban for a long time upon multiple shorter time triggers. Currently, I have it set to just ban for a long time upon the first trigger.

```
#######################################################################
# USER DEFINED CHAIN SUBROUTINES:
#
# http-new-in4
#
# A NEW Connection on port 80 part 4.
#
# multiple hits on the banned list means you get a one day ban.
# (I re-load the firewall rule set often, so going longer makes
# little sense.)
#
# Custom tables must exist before being referenced, hence the order
# of these sub-toutines.
#
# Place holder routine, but tested. Logs if a day ban would have
# been activated.
#
$IPTABLES -N http-new-in4
#$IPTABLES -A http-new-in4 -m recent --set --name HTTP_BAN_DAY

$IPTABLES -A http-new-in4 -j LOG --log-prefix "DAY80:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in4 -j DROP

#######################################################################
# USER DEFINED CHAIN SUBROUTINES:
#
# http-new-in3
#
# A NEW Connection on port 80 part 3.
#
# carry forward to the actual banned list:
# Increment this count. Leave the previous count.
#
# Custom tables must exist before being referenced, hence the order
# of these sub-toutines.
#
$IPTABLES -N http-new-in3
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in3 -m recent --remove --name HTTP_02
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in3 -m recent --update --hitcount 1 --seconds 86400 --name HTTP_BAN -j http-new-in4
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in3 -m recent --set --name HTTP_BAN

$IPTABLES -A http-new-in3 -j LOG --log-prefix "BAN80:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in3 -j DROP

#######################################################################
# USER DEFINED CHAIN SUBROUTINES:
#
# http-new-in2
#
# A NEW Connection on port 80 part 2.
#
# carry forward from previous max new connections per unit time:
# Increment this count and clear the lesser significant count.
#
$IPTABLES -N http-new-in2
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in2 -m recent --remove --name HTTP_01
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in2 -m recent --update --hitcount 3 --seconds 720 --name HTTP_02 -j http-new-in3
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in2 -m recent --set --name HTTP_02

$IPTABLES -A http-new-in2 -j LOG --log-prefix "CARRY80:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in2 -j ACCEPT

#######################################################################
# USER DEFINED CHAIN SUBROUTINES:
#
# http-new-in
#
# A NEW Connection on port 80:
#
$IPTABLES -N http-new-in

echo Allowing EXTERNAL access to the WWW server

# . check the static blacklist.
#
# http related
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -i $EXTIF -s 5.248.83.0/24 -j DROP
... delete a bunch on entries ...
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -i $EXTIF -s 195.211.152.0/22 -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -i $EXTIF -s 198.27.126.38 -j DROP

# . check the dynamic banned list
#
# The 1 Hour banned list (bumped to more than a day):
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -m recent --update --seconds 90000 --name HTTP_BAN --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix "LIM80:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -m recent --update --seconds 90000 --name HTTP_BAN --rsource -j DROP

# A generic log entry. Usually only during degugging
#
#$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -j LOG --log-prefix "NEW80ALL:" --log-level info

# Dynamic Badguy List. Least significant hit counter.  Detect and DROP Bad IPs that do excessive connections to port 80.
#
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -m recent --update --hitcount 20 --seconds 240 --name HTTP_01 -j http-new-in2
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -m recent --set --name HTTP_01

$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -j LOG --log-prefix "NEW80:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -j ACCEPT

... a bunch of stuff not included here

# Allow any related traffic coming back to the server in.
#
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -s $UNIVERSE -d $EXTIP -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

... the above is needed before the below ...

# If required, go to NEW HTTP connection sub-routine
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m state --state NEW -p tcp -s $UNIVERSE -d $EXTIP --dport 80 -j http-new-in
```